# Why need use [self class] when invoking your own class methods?

Tags: objective-c, self, class-method

I read a topic at here 
http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-05-14-what-every-apple-programmer-should-know.html. Mike said that "Always use [self class] when invoking your own class methods". But I don't understand why. Can you give an example ?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question stems from a lack of clarity about what a [class method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html) is, i.e. those methods whose implementations start with a `+` and are used for the class, not a particular instance of an object of that class as opposed to instance methods (those whose implementations start with `-`) that we see more frequently, or whether you have a question about use use of `[self class]` construct.

Comment: I mean about why use `[[self class] method]` instead of `[className method]`

Comment: Ah. It's useful in case your object has been subclassed and you might want to use the subclass rendition of the method, so you enjoy the full behavior of the subclass, i.e. use the version of the `method` from the subclass.

Answer (score 7):

Lets say that you have class `foo`, which have the following methods:

```
+(NSString*) bar{ return @"bar"; }

-(NSString*) barMethod{ return [[self class] bar]; }
```

Now lets say that you have a class `foo2` which inherits from `foo`. If you override

```
+(NSString*) bar { return @"bar2" }
```

the method `barMethod` will return `bar2`, as you probably intended for it to.

Comment: `[foo barMethod]` and `[foo2 barMethod]` is OK, too ? Which problem ?

Comment: @DungLe My answer is just a concrete example of this answer with a few more details.  This answer is very much correct, just a bit brief.   Liye deserves the magic internet karma points more than I, but a comment was too short to plop down concrete code.

Comment: A real-world example is the `layerClass` method of `UIView`.

Comment: @DungLe: The code `[[self class] bar]` is in the `barMethod` method of the class `foo`. However, if you call `barMethod` on an object of class `foo2`, it will return `@"bar2"`. If you had hardcoded some class inside `barMethod`, that would not be possible.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike other OO languages, class methods in Objective-C are both inherited **and can be overridden**.

Thus, if you have:

```
@immplementation Abstract // : NSObject
- (void) doSomethingClassy
{
    [Abstract classyThing];
}

+ (void) classyThing
{
    ... some classy code ...;
}
@end

@interface Concrete : Abstract
@end
@implementation Concrete
+ (void) classyThing
{
    ... some classy code ...;
    [super classThing];
}
@end
```

Then this won't call Concrete's `+classyThing` from Abstract's implementation of `doSomethingClassy`:

```
[[[Concrete alloc] init] doSomethingClassy];
```

Whereas if you modify `doSomethingClassy` to do `[[self class] classyThing];` it'll work as expected.

(note that this is a concrete example of Liye Zhang's answer -- feel free to mark his correct as he was first, just not with quite as concrete of an example)

Comment: The results appear to be the same (from some test I've just run) whether you do `[[self class] someClassMethod]` or `[self someClassMethod]`. So I don't see the point to using `[self class]` over just `self` to call a class method.

Comment: @rmaddy Inside a class method, it doesn't matter whether you say `self` or `[self class]`, since `+[NSObject class]` is defined as `return self`.  In an instance method, you must say `[self class]`.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks. I get that. But it is still unclear why you would choose `[[self class] someClassMethod]` over `[self someClassMethod]` in a class method. Is the only reason in case you change the class method making the call into an instance method?

Comment: Where did you see an example of `[[self class] someClassMethod]` in a class method?

Comment: Note that the example is with an instance method.  In a class method, just use `self`.

Comment: @robmayoff Ugh! Reading comprehension failure. Reading the OP's question and the blog left me thinking just about class methods. I glossed right over the fact that this was dealing with calling a class method from an instance method. I'll leave you alone now. Thanks. :)